# rule for compound verbs and pronoun substitution

Tags: pronouns, phrasal-verbs

These statements are ok:

1. "I looked George up."
2. "I looked up George."
3. "I looked him up."

But this is not ok: "I looked up him."

In this case, it's not possible to substitute the pronoun "him" for "George". What rule prohibits this substitution?

Comment: The final constituent has to bear stress, and personal pronouns normally don't bear stress, so they generally don't appear in this position.

Comment: In other words, the order 'verb + particle + object' is not possible if the object is an unstressed personal pronoun. So we can replace "George" by unstressed "him" in "I looked him up" but not in "I looked up him".